# Cortex A53 L1 L2 caches info

Tags: caching, arm, microcontroller, cpu-cache

Looking into [Cortex A53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE0Yz.png), I am trying to figure out what exactly are:

1. 8-64k I-Cache w/parity

   - What is the meaning of 8-64k? Is it 8-way set associative cache with a size of 64kByte? or is just saying the size is in a range of 8~64kByte
   - What is "w/parity"?
2. 8-64k D-Cache w/ECC

   - What is "w/ECC"?
3. The associativity (direct map, 2-way, 4-way ...etc) and size of L1 and L2 caches are fixed for [Cortex A53](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OE0Yz.png) or is really up to the developer to adjust while designing the microcontroller?

Comment: the core can be optionally compiled to use parity or not or to use ecc or not, you have to use more memory in the design

Comment: someone beat me to it ,was going to have you do the work to look at the technical reference manual which contains the answers you seek...

Comment: these are generally not runtime options they are compile time options, and the a53 is not a microcontroller...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0500e/DDI0500E_cortex_a53_r0p3_trm.pdf#G4.5073149) spec, this is implementation specific and can support sizes between 8 and 64k. It's not the set associativity since that's only 2 for the I-cache.

Parity means that you have parity bits added for error detection. ECC stands for Error-correction-code which is more advanced (more bits covering different subsets of the line) and can use for error correction as well as detection.

Comment: Thanks Leeor, that is the document I was looking for, all my questions are answered now.